# accessing "html_soup" from outside the class in python

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup

I am very new to this using classes thing

i am trying to call the html_soup variable so that I can use it outside of the class

I have the class defined like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

class DataScrape():
    def __init__(self, website):
        self.website = website
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
           executable_path=r"C:/Users/littl/Downloads/"
        + "chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
        # self.options = Options()
        # self.options.add_argument("--headless")# Runs Chrome in headless mode.
        # self.options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')# # Bypass OS security model
        # self.options.add_argument('start-maximized')
        # self.options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
        # self.options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=self.options,
        # executable_path=
        # r'C:/Users/littl/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

    def bs4Scrape(self, urlToScrape):
        req = Request(urlToScrape, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        web_byte = urlopen(req).read()
        webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
        self.html_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')

    def seleniumNavigate(self):     
        self.driver.get(self.website)     

imdbScrape = DataScrape("https://www.imdb.com/")
imdbScrape.seleniumNavigate()
wait = WebDriverWait(imdbScrape.driver, 10)
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                            '//*[@id="suggestion-search"]'))).send_keys("the"
                            + " fifth element")

firstSelection = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                 '//*[@id="react-autowhatever-1--'
                                 + 'item-0"]/span')))
firstSelection.location_once_scrolled_into_view
firstSelection.click()
imdbUrlToScrape = imdbScrape.driver.current_url
imdbScrape.driver.close()
print(imdbScrape.html_soup)
```

I am attempting to call it like this:

```
  imdbScrape.bs4Scrape(imdbUrlToScrape).html_soup
```

but when compiling it says:

```
NoneType' object has no attribute 'html_soup'
```

how do i write the code in away that I can access the html_soup outside of the class

I'm guessing I have to define the variable in another way but am not sure how to do this

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Wouldn’t `html_soup` be an attribute of the class, based on your code?

Comment: to be honest, I am not sure this is the first time I have ever used the class system, I attempted a few things but an not sure how to utilize it correctly

Comment: `imdbScrape.bs4Scrape(imdbUrlToScrape).html_soup` is a mess, because you're doing the function call or method call (on a function that returns None) and trying to access the attribute it set in the *same* line. Don't do that. The `html_soup` is set on the *instance* of the class.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your code, and I'm no expert in OOP, but I currently don't see the need for a class. Do try `imdbScrape.html_soup`. Note that variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, I tried that with no success but thanks for the tip

Comment: @ParitoshSingh thanks for the info, I agree it's a mess but am not sure how to clean it up so that I can access the "html_soup" outside of the instance of the class (like i mentioned super new to the class thing)

Comment: _with no success_ Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have added all of my code maybe that will help a little to visualize what i am going for 
@AlexanderCécile it gives me that error that "NoneType' object has no attribute 'html_soup'"

Comment: @littlejiver Do `imdbScrape.bs4Scrape(imdbUrlToScrape)` first. Notice, you're *already* using the concept of accessing something on the *instance* of the class (in this case, the instance/object is imdbScrape, for the class DataScrape). *Then* separately do `imdbScrape.html_soup` because `html_soup` is set on the *instance*. Essentially, classes are nothing special, just some extra syntax.

Comment: @littlejiver : Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @Kunduk not exactly, I expanded some of the function I was writing for bs4scrape (now Imdbbs4scrape) so 6 of one half a dozen of the other